# Performance of SortedList.Last with predicate

Tags: c#, .net, performance, binary-search, sortedlist

I would like to find the value of the last item in a SortedList that is under a certain value. Since SortedList is implemented with something capable of binary searches, this is possible in O(log(n)).

What will the performance of this code be:

```
data.Last(x => x.Key < 100);
```

I can only find documentation for Enumerable.Last ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549138(v=vs.90).aspx ) and I want to make sure it doesn't use a generic enumerator-based implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SortedList` performs the same as any `IEnumerable<T>` for `.Last` method, both are O(n);

Comment: .Last(), just like .First(), also enumerates from the front of the list, so if your item is near the back you'll see near the worst case O(n) performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your question with another question. How would `SortedList` utilize its inherent sorting to do better than O(n) for any arbitrary predicate?

Unless you make assumptions about the predicate you essentially have to use a standard enumerator approach